# Motor, a gearbox and a drum with a cable lifting a mass

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, gears, dynamics

A lifting device consists of an electric motor, a gearbox and a drum with a cable for lifting a mass.

The speed after the initial acceleration is $v=0.5\,\text{m/s}$.

The gear efficiency $\eta=0.7$

Maximum motor torque is $T=15 \, \text{Nm}$

Motor inertia $J_m=0.005 \, \text{kgm}^2$

Drum diameter $d = 0.5 \, \text{m}$

Motor rotating speed after initial acceleration $n=2600\, \text{rpm}$

The inertia of the drum $J_L$ is considered small and thus neglected.

I want to Calculate how much time it takes for the motor to accelerate the mass $m=510 \,\text{kg}$ from standstill upwards to the given speed. Assume constant acceleration.

[image]

I know applying Newton's second law that:

$$F-mg=ma$$ and then we get the acceleration

$$a=\frac{F-mg}{m}$$ and the speed v

$$v=at$$ so $$t=\frac{mv}{F-mg}$$

The motor rotates the geared system $\omega_M$ and the geared system rotates the drum $\omega_L$.

The mass $m$ causes the torque $T_L=mgr$ on the rope drum. So the power of the load is $P_L=T_L\omega_L$. And therefore $\eta P_m=P_L$ and there I get the $\omega_L$ when $$\omega_L=\frac{\eta\, T_m\, \omega_m}{T_L}$$

But how do I get force $F$ so I can calculate the time or is there better way to do this?

Or can I calculate the acceleration $a = \frac{T}{J_{motor}}$

Answer (score 1):

Since this mechanism is all rigidly coupled, it has one degree-of-freedom. One differential equation combined with boundary conditions is enough to describe the position, velocity and acceleration of the system.

#### Steps for main problem:

1. Compute missing gear ratio as it is a useful parameter: $i=\frac{\omega_M}{\omega_L} = \frac{\frac{2\pi}{60}}{\frac{v}{r}}$
2. Transform interia: In order to do derive the equation of motion you have to transform all inertia values to ONE position in the described 'force chain'. I take the hanging load as my transformation target as it is of linear kind of motion and hence more intuitive than rotary kind. The transformation itself is nicely derived in [here](http://www.mechanics.iei.liu.se/edu_ug/tmme11/reduced) and many mechanics textbooks.

   - Transformed motor inertia $m_{M->L} = \frac{J_M \cdot i^2}{r^2}$ in $[kg]$
   - Transformed drum inertia $m_{D->L} = \frac{J_D}{r^2}$ in $[kg]$
   - Load inertia $m_L$ stays the same
3. Transform forces acting on the mechanism: This is mainly the motor torque $T_M$ which I assume is a constant. It is reduced by $\eta$ which is the constant power loss in the geartrain.  There is also a static force $G$ neccessary to prevent the load from falling down.

   - Transformed motor torque $F_{M->L} = T_M \cdot i\cdot \eta$ in $[N]$
   - Weight of load $G_L = m_L \cdot g$
4. Build differential equation according Newtons 2nd law: $ m \cdot a = \sum{F}$

   - $(m_{M->L} + m_{D->L} + m_{L})  \cdot a = F_{M->L} - G_L$
   - $(\frac{J_M \cdot i^2}{r^2} + \frac{J_D}{r^2} + m_L)  \cdot a = T_M \cdot i\cdot \eta - m_L \cdot g $
5. Since all parameters are known you can solve for $a$ which is a constant value. Integrating a over a time period $\Delta t_a$ gives you the velocity $v$ of the load, which is given above. Finally:

   $\Delta t_a = \frac{v}{a} = \frac{v \cdot (\frac{J_M \cdot i^2}{r^2} + \frac{J_D}{r^2} + m_L)}{T_M \cdot i\cdot \eta - m_L \cdot g}$

   BTW: The nominator of the fraction is the impulse of the system, the denominator the force trying to change the impulse.

#### About transformation of inertia:

- Assuming a lossless gearbox, there is conservation of power:

  $P_1 = T_1 \omega_1 = P_2 = T_2 \omega_2 $
- Basic kinematic relationship gives a fixed ratio between input and output:

  $\frac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = \frac{\dot\omega_2}{\dot\omega_1} = i$
- Newtons 2nd law gives:

  $ J_1 \cdot \dot\omega_1 = T_1$ and $ J_2 \cdot \dot\omega_2 = T_2$
- and you can write by dividing the equations above and using the gear ratio:

  $\frac{T_2}{T_1} = \frac{\dot\omega_2}{\dot\omega_1} \cdot \frac{J_2}{J_1}= i \cdot \frac{J_2}{J_1} $
- Use the conservation of power and replace the ration of torques with the equation above:

  $\frac{T_2}{T_1} = \frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2} => i \cdot \frac{J_2}{J_1} = \frac{1}{i} => J_1 = i^2 \cdot J_2$

When you crank a machine at side 2 with a gearbox with a ratio $i=2$:

1. you need *half* the torque compared to cranking on the output shaft $T_2= \frac{1}{2}\cdot T_1$
2. you need to crank *twice* as much for a certain rpm at the load $\omega_2 = 2 \cdot \omega_1 $
3. the inertia of the load (e.g. a flywheel) *you* feel is cut down by factor of *four* $J_2 = \frac{1}{2^2}\cdot J_1$

One could also say the moment of inertia is ***reduced***, but only for this common case. If you sit on the output shaft, the motor inertia gets amplified. So probably it's better to speak of a ***transformed*** mass moment of inertia. In the case of a lossy gearbox, the torque gets decreased by the efficiency, but the general relation $J_1 = i^2 \cdot J_2$ still holds true.

BTW: For drive machines there is a gear ratio leading to an optimum regarding rotational acceleration: $ i_{opt} = \sqrt{\frac{J_2}{J_1}}$.